# Using callbacks with action creators

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, redux, axios

I am making a POST request upon completion I'd like to redirect the user to a new page using a callback. Below is my onSubmit handler.

```
 onSubmit(values) {
        console.log('before action');
        this.props.createPost(values, () => {
            console.log('callback fired');
            this.props.history.push('/someotherpage');
        });
    }
```

Here is my action creator.

```
export function createPost(values, callback) {
    const request = axios.post(`/api/create_post`, values)
        .then(() => callback());

    return {
        type: CREATE_POST,
        payload: request
    };
}
```

I was expecting the callback to redirect me to another page but it doesn't do that. The data does get sent to the database but the callback doesn't fire.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: nope just the 'before action' log. correction. after some time this pops up. POST http://localhost:3000/api/create_listing net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: and this. createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error

Answer (score 1):

According to the error messages you added in the comments, your HTTP call fails, and the promise is rejected. As a result, the `.then()` handler is never called.

Add error handling via a `.catch()` handler, and you should be able to process the (failed) call result.

Comment: Thanks!...so I didn't include a res.send in my express api endpoint. Once I put that in, callback fired and redirected my page.